# Add root, before merging two XML-Files

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I got two XML-Files and I create a new File with the two files in it. The Problem here is, that both have different root nodes and when both are merged together I receive actually what I wanted to do, but with two different root nodes and thats not XML-conform. So how can I add a default node before the rest is inserted?

The structure looks like this:

File 1:

```
<rootFile1>
  //dataFile1
</rootFile1>
```

File 2:

```
<rootFile2>
  //dataFile2
</rootFile2>
```

combined to:

```
//missing root
  <rootFile1>
    //dataFile1
  </rootFile1>
  <rootFile2>
    //dataFile2
  </rootFile2>
//missing root
```

I need a wrapper node here, for the combined file.

My code looks like this:

```
    XmlTextReader xmlreader1 = new XmlTextReader(@"N:\File.xml");
    XmlTextReader xmlreader2 = new XmlTextReader(@"N:\File2.xml");

    using (var output = System.IO.File.Create(@"N:\OutputFile.xml"))
    {
        XElement root = new XElement("root");
        foreach (var file in new[] { @"N:\File.xml", @"N:\File2.xml" })
        {
            using (var input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                input.CopyTo(output);
            }
        }
        root.Add(output);
    }
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load("N:\File.xml");
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load("N:\File2.xml");
XDocument merged = new XDocument(new XElement("root", doc1.Root, doc2.Root));
merged.Save("N:\Merged.xml");
```